# How do I embed an instagram post in my React app

Tags: reactjs, instagram

From our api I can query (with graphQL) the instagram `id` and the `url` from the specific instagram post.

Is [react-instagram-embed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-instagram-embed) the way to go?

Or do I just create some HTML and add the instagram `embed` code and fetch the `id` and `url` and replace those in the `embed` code?

How do I embed this my React app?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use graphQL in your backend I recommend you perform schema stitching. That would be , 'stitching' Instagram's GraphQL API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) with your GraphQL API. This would allow you to perform queries as usually on your schema , even if some parts of them would come from Instagram's API. This is done through introspection. In order to stitch your schema with the wanted remote schema you should use `graphql-tools` 's  schema stitching (https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-stitching/stitch-combining-schemas). This allows for smooth querying ( you can also create 'links' between the two schemas).

Answer (score 0):

Using react-instagram-embed is an okay option (also the most popular). You can always create your own solution for any library if you have enough time.